# How can I find out when I logged in without administrator access?

Tags: windows-7, login, event-log, standard-user

How can I find out when I logged in without administrator access on `Win 7`?

It doesn't let me open the `Security Log` in `Event Viewer`.

Is there another way to find this out?

Comment: Have you tried launching event viewer as administrator?

Comment: @BenPlont I don't have administrator access on the machine

Answer (score 0):

The following will give the last login time, but no further history.

From command prompt:

```
net user <username>
```